# Latex text goes out of bottom margine and get clipped

Tags: tables, pdftex, margins, paragraphs, longtabu

[image]

Following is the code that gives the wired result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{book}

%enable linespacing commands%
\usepackage{setspace}
%set onehalf line spacing
\onehalfspacing

%enable H option that prevent figure floats
\usepackage{float}

%used to import graphics%
\usepackage{graphicx}

%used for referencing%
\usepackage{harvard}

%customise chapter styles%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}

%set bibliography listing style to agsm%
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

%set margins%
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

%keep only the page number%
\pagestyle{plain}

%allows to create tables with different column widths%
\usepackage{tabularx}

%allows to create tables that can span accross pages%
\usepackage{longtable}%dependency of longtabu
\usepackage{tabu}%contains longtabu

%enable support for source code
% this package needs the python package 'sudo pip install pygments'
%add pdfLaTeX option -shell-escape
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}




\begin{figure}%[H]
\centering
\caption{possible example composition of a Cgui GUI}
\label{fig:cgui_square}
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
\end{figure}




% begining of the table
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth { X[1 , l ]  X[1 , l ] }
\label{table:xxxx_xxxxx}\\
\caption{xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx }\\
% -----------------headings----------------------%
\hline
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx}
&
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx}
\\
\hline
\endfirsthead

%headings for next page columns
\hline
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx}
&
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx}
\\
\hline
\endhead

%this is printed before the table is broken into the next page
\multicolumn{2}{r}{Continued on next page} \\
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot
% ---------------headings end--------------------%
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
&
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
\\

\hline
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
&
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
\\

\hline
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
&
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
\\

\hline
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
&
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
\\
%-------------------body end---------------------%
\end{longtabu}
% end of the table



\paragraph{}
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxx




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

lt chooses a better pagebreak in this case if you allow the table to be `[h]` so it is out of the queue before the long table starts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{book}

%enable linespacing commands%
\usepackage{setspace}
%set onehalf line spacing
\onehalfspacing

%enable H option that prevent figure floats
\usepackage{float}

%used to import graphics%
\usepackage{graphicx}

%used for referencing%
\usepackage{harvard}

%customise chapter styles%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE}

%set bibliography listing style to agsm%
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

%set margins%
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

%keep only the page number%
\pagestyle{plain}

%allows to create tables with different column widths%
\usepackage{tabularx}

%allows to create tables that can span accross pages%
\usepackage{longtable}%dependency of longtabu
\usepackage{tabu}%contains longtabu

%enable support for source code
% this package needs the python package 'sudo pip install pygments'
%add pdfLaTeX option -shell-escape
%\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}




\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\caption{possible example composition of a Cgui GUI}
\label{fig:cgui_square}
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
sdl kfj slkdfj klsdjfklsj dfkl jskldfj klsj kl
sdf kjsdhf kjsdh fkj
sd fjhgsd fkjhsdkf
\end{figure}



% begining of the table
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth { X[1 , l ]  X[1 , l ] }
\label{table:xxxx_xxxxx}\\
\caption{xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx }\\
% -----------------headings----------------------%
\hline
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx}
&
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx}
\\
\hline
\endfirsthead

%headings for next page columns
\hline
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx}
&
\textbf{xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx}
\\
\hline
\endhead

%this is printed before the table is broken into the next page
\multicolumn{2}{r}{Continued on next page} \\
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot
% ---------------headings end--------------------%
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
&
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
\\

\hline
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
&
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
\\

\hline
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
&
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
\\

\hline
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
&
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
\\
%-------------------body end---------------------%
\end{longtabu}
% end of the table



\paragraph{}
xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxx




\end{document}
```

Comment: I am very new to latex. Will you please be able to direct me to a link where explains what is happening here (the logic).

Comment: I applied your solution to my real document which is same as the example I posted ( as I learnt from you yesterday ) except for the characters and the picture inside the figure. There the solution failed. Still the text goes beyond the margin.

Comment: @Makmeksam to your first comment, there is no logic, interfacing a multipage table when there are pending floats that may or may not be added is hard and there's a bug. using h just avoids it (sometimes)

Comment: goes off the bottom margin? you could try applying a patch, I'll look up the link

Comment: take a local copy of longtable.sty and modify according to http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=tools/3512   I'd be interested to know if it worked

Comment: @Makmeksam I don't understand this too. When `\insert` is processed and contributed to the current page, then `\pagegoal` is recalculated. Then `longtable` must know the amount of free space. And when `longtable` decides that it is not long and it fits to one page, then the next paragraph must be processed normally.

Comment: Is there any chance that i can find an already patched longtable.sty? And is the patch a sure solution? ANd isn't my case common to many? AM I doing anything in an inferior way?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong although it's quite unusual to have longtables that are so short (there is a clue in the name) the problem only occurs if the longtable and a normal floating table both fit on the same page, so it is relatively rare

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I applied the patch you mentioned. And it worked. Thank you very much for that answer. Btw, I used longtabu because I wanted to use the same table all over my doc. I could use booktab if it can span the table over multiple pages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle would it be better if I replace all the small longtabu with tabularx or tabular?

Comment: @Makmeksam  Well if the bug fix works just stay with what you have:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanx for the advice :)